# Options for centralized IIS 6.0 management

Tags: iis, configuration

I manage several IIS 6.0 web servers for many different sites, most of which are set up in a load balanced configuration, which requires the same IIS admin procedure to be duplicated across N number of machines. Is there a centralized management tool I can use to do this? What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your best bet is to use VBScript to do the setup. Here's a short example:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20010609.asp

Microsoft also has a guide available for programmatically administering IIS 6:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9041b0a5-c314-46d9-8f56-01506687f357.mspx